# Sphinx Search missing results

Tags: symfony, sphinx

I am using Sphinx with Symfony2 to serach people in my db. 
The strange behavior is:
I search for **Jim J** and the result is:

- James 'Jim' Singer
- Jim Abrahams
- Jim Anderson
- Jim Backus
- Jim Bennon
- ...

If i search for **Jim Ja** the result is:

- James 'Jim' Singer
- Jim Jansen
- Jim Jarmusch
- ...

Why am i missing the "Ja" results if i just search for Jim J, but i get all the others?

Here is the source and index code:

```
source peopleautocomplete {

sql_query           = SELECT id, firstName, lastName, pseudonym FROM Person

sql_attr_string     = pseudonym
sql_attr_string     = firstName
sql_attr_string     = lastName
}

index peopleautocomplete
{
source              = peopleautocomplete
path                = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/peopleautocomplete
docinfo             = extern
charset_type        = utf-8
min_word_len        = 2
enable_star         = 1
min_prefix_len      = 1
}
```

And the php code:

```
<?php
    $q = $request->query->get('q');
    $aq = explode(' ', $q);
    if (strlen($aq[count($aq) - 1]) < 2) {
        $query = $q;
    } else {
        $query = $q . '*';
    }
    $result = $this->_getSearchEngine()->searchEx($query, 'peopleautocomplete');
?>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why am i missing the "Ja" results if i just search for Jim J, but i get all the others?

Both search words 'Jim' and 'J' match Jim. So `Jim Abrahams` is valid (it matches both query words). The others are not 'missing' they just dropped off the bottom because so many matches.

Can just use `"Jim J"` to search them as as phrase (your code should add the stars needed) - will require two matching words.

But that would disallow middle names. To allow for that couple of options
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax

perhaps the easiest is the strict order operator.

`Jim << J`

Or if want to allow people to enter Surname, followed by surname, could just use proximity or even NEAR

---

Edit: looking again, see your code wont actually add stars correctly. Its adding to every space seperated token, even if itself is a operator.

```
<?php $query = preg_replace('/(\w{2,}\b)/','$1*',$query);
```

is more effective, and more compact!

Or `expand_keywords` option on the index to do it transparently.